# Url amigável para MVC

Tags: htaccess

Estou tentando criar um .htaccess  para deixar os urls do site amigaveis, a exibição de página será sempre na index pois estou usando MVC. Estou seguindo um  padrao com o parametro ato na url para indicar qual classe e metodo executar. Exemplo

site/index.php?ato=conta'fazerlogin

Conta é parte do nome da minha classe que chama ControllerConta e fazerlogin é um  método da mesmo.

outros exemplos são:

site/index.php?ato=conta'editarusuario&id=2

Aqui chamo o metodo para editar o usuario e passo o id  do usuario.

Queria que ficasse assim:

site/conta/fazerlogin

site/conta/editarusuario/1

Tentei de alguns jeitos mas nem vou colocar as tentativas pois eles nem funcionaram, deu erro Bad Internet.

Comment: Não deu pra entender a url `site/index.php?ato=conta'editarusuario&id=2`, poderia corrigir?

Comment: Aqui tem o que você precisa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url+amigável

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento creio que ele está usando o `'` como separador

Comment: @Bacco se for isso é bem confuso, Ivcs sei que vai parecer exagero meu, mas já pensou em usar algum sistema de rotas pronto, como framewroks tipo o Laravel, Lumen ou cakePHP?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ou o velho e bom explode :D - Essa técnica é sub-utilizada, mas acho bem mais limpa que passar coisa por parâmetro. example.com/route.php/roupas/camisetas

Comment: MVC nada tem a ver com url amigável.

Comment: E grande chance de ser duplicata de alguma das [2103467463 perguntas sobre htaccess do site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url+amig%C3%A1vel).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento parece sim, mas quando falei do explode, não me referia à pergunta, e sim ao exemplo que eu dei. O dele é por parâmetro, então o ' não ajuda muito. Eu acho legal totalmente sem parâmetros.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento No PATH_INFO, que pega só o que vem depois do .php

Comment: fiquei com receio em responder, mas fui no embalo e postei.. rsrsr

Comment: O ' é um separador mesmo, estou usando ele pois o resto da equipe é iniciante e poderiam colocar parametros invalidos, assim fica mais padronizado. Jà tinha pesquisado aqui e em outros  lugares, achei alguns arquivos, editei pra enquadrar no projeto mas só dá o Bad Internet. Sobre MVC, realmente tem nada haver, mas como a estrutura de arquivos é diferente,os exemplos que achei se distinguiam. Sobre os frameworks nunca tinha ouvido falar, não sou de usar framework, valeu a dica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No meu caso o que funcionou foi:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?ato=$1 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?objeto=$1&ato=$2 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?objeto=$1&ato=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma das soluções que utilizo é:

No .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

#Options -Indexes
```

No index.php

```
  <?php
  //EXPLODE A URL PASSADA
  $URI = urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  $url = explode ("/", $URI);

  var_dump($url); //veja como fica a saída
  ?>
```

$url passa a ser um array que contem o caminho passado na url.

Exemplo:
http://site/pagina/acao

No `$url[0]` terá o valor: **pagina** e no `$url[1]` terá o valor **acao**

Com isso você pode fazer os includs desejados e pegar a acao passada.

Comment: apresenta o erro: `Internal Server Error`

Comment: Verifique se o **RewriteBase** está setado para o pasta que está seu index.php. Exemplo: se no meu servidor a pasta exemplo é **urlamigavel**, o RewriteBase deve ser **RewriteBase /urlamigaval/**

Answer (score 0):

## Regras de reescrita no .htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Redirect Trailing Slashes.
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.+) /

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

A regra é simples. Simplesmente envia a query inteira para o arquivo definido como índice de diretório (document root / directory index). No caso acima, o arquivo index.php

Com isso poderá manipular a query da URL como quiser, sem precisar criar novas regras para cada novo parâmetro.

No index.php, basta receber a query e fazer os devidos tratamentos.

Nesse exemplo abaixo, peguei partes de um framework particular que desenvolvo há muitos anos. A parte que abstrai URI e parâmetros GET e POST, converti para um estilo procedural, sem uso de classes, oop, etc. Para que iniciantes entendam e tirem proveito.

```
/*
Define a base da URL.
Caso queria executar num subfolder, basta especificar aqui.
Exemplo, http://localhost/pastateste/index.php
$href_base = '/pastateste/';
*/
$href_base = '/';

/*
Define o arquivo índice. Pode definir um arquivo diferente do definido em document root ou directory index seja u
Exemplo, http://localhost/pastateste/outro.php
$file_base = 'outro.php';
*/
$file_base = 'index.php';

$rs['path'] = null;
$rs['query'] = null;
$rs['post'] = null;

/*
Verifica em qual ambiente está sendo executado este script.
Tudo que começar com "cli", indica que está sob Command Line Interface.
*/
$cli_mode = ((substr(PHP_SAPI, 0, 3) == 'cli')? true : false);
$uri = (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : (isset($_SERVER['argv'][1])? $_SERVER['argv'][1] : ''));
$arr = parse_url($uri);

if (isset($arr['path']) && !empty($arr['path'])) {
    $rs['path'] = $arr['path'];
    unset($arr['path']);

    /**
    Checking for base path and remove it.
    */
    if (strpos($rs['path'], $href_base) === 0) {
        $rs['path'] = substr($rs['path'], strlen($href_base));
    }

    /**
    Checking for file base path and remove it.
    */
    if (strpos($rs['path'], $file_base) === 0) {
        $rs['path'] = substr($rs['path'], strlen($file_base));
        $rs['path'] = trim($rs['path'], '/');
    }

    /**
    Convert the parameter to array.
    */
    if (!empty($rs['path'])) {
        $rs['path'] = explode('/', $rs['path']);
    }

}

/**
Convert the URI query to array.
*/
if (isset($arr['query']) && !empty($arr['query'])) {
    parse_str($arr['query'], $rs['query']);
}

/**
Get the POST array.
*/
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    $rs['post'] = $_POST;
}

/*
Contém os dados extraídos da query uri
Exemplo: http://localhost/foo/bar
Retornará 
array(0 => 'foo', 1 => 'bar')
*/
print_r($rs['path']);

/*
Contém os dados extraídos da variável global $_GET
Exemplo: http://localhost/?foo=1&bar=2
Retornará 
array('foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2)
*/
print_r($rs['query']);

/*
Contém os dados extraídos da variável global $_GET
Exemplo: 
<form action="http://localhost/" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="bar" value="2" />
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
Retornará 
array('foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2)
*/
print_r($rs['post']);
```

Resumindo, o resultado que interessa estará dentro do array `$rs`. Basta manipular esse array conforme desejar.

## Invocando a classe e o método resgatados da URI

Pegando o exemplo da pergunta `site/index.php?ato=conta'fazerlogin`.

Eu não recomendo fazer dessa forma, usando um caracter de single quote como separador.

No exemplo que postei, bastaria fazer assim

```
http://site/conta/fazerlogin
```

Então esses dados da query seriam resgatados em `$rs['path']`.

Para chamar a classe:

```
/*
Obviamente precisamos verificar se os parâmetros existem:
*/
if (
    isset($rs['path'][0])
    && isset($rs['path'][1])
) {
    $c = trim($rs['path'][0]);
    $m = trim($rs['path'][1]);
} else {
    /*
    Isso aqui é para testes somente. Faça o tratamento adequado conforme o seu caso.
    Recomendo que direcione para uma classe padrão.
    */
    echo 'classe ou méotodo não informado'; exit;
}

if (
    !empty($c)
    && !empty($m)
) {

    if (class_exists($c)) {

        /*
        Aqui usamos o Reflection para poder instanciar um objeto caso não seja estático. Se for estático, será executado estaticamente.
        */
        $reflection = new \ReflectionMethod($c, $m);
        /*
        Aqui também tomamos cuidado para checar se o método é publico.
        O método deve ser definido como público para ser acessível.
        */
        if ($reflection->isPublic()) {
            if ($reflection->isStatic()) {
                /*
                Invoca de forma estática.
                */
                $data = $c::$m();
            } else {
                /*
                Invoca como instância.
                */
                $c = new $c;
                $data = $c->$m();
            }
            print_r($data);
        } else {
            /*
            Isso aqui é para testes somente. Faça o tratamento adequado conforme o seu caso.
            A decisão aqui depende de opinião pessoal. Avalie o que deseja fazer aqui pois pode-se aceitar um método inexistente ou negar a requisição. Isso dependerá do seu modelo de negócios.
            Note que não foi necessário preocupar-se com method_exists(), pois a classe ReflectionMethod já faz esse trabalho.
            */
            echo 'classe ou método vazios'; exit;
        }
    } else {
        /*
        Isso aqui é para testes somente. Faça o tratamento adequado conforme o seu caso.
        Recomendo que direcione para uma classe que retorne um aviso de página inexistente ao usuário.
        Aqui por exemplo, pode invocar uma classe que emita um http status 404 not found.
        Claro que, se estiver trabalhando com design MVC, faça tudo dentro de sua respectiva camada.
        */
        echo 'classe ou méotodo vazios'; exit;
    }
} else {
    /*
    Isso aqui é para testes somente. Faça o tratamento adequado conforme o seu caso.
    Recomendo que direcione para uma classe padrão.
    */
    echo 'classe ou méotodo vazios'; exit;
}

class conta
{
    public function fazerlogin()
    {
        return 'aqui retorna o for necessário';
    }
}
```

## Recursos adicionais do script que abstrai os parâmetros da query URI.

O script é compatível com execuções por linha de comando (cli)

```
C:\pasta\onde\instalou\o\php\php.exe C:\www\site\index.php conta/fazerlogin
```

Fake URL Rewrite (reescrita de url falsa).

```
http://site/index.php/conta/fazerlogin
```

URL normal. (Essa parte não está demonstrada nos scripts acima)

```
http://site/index.php/?p=conta/fazerlogin
```

## Observação

Os exemplos acima são meramente didáticos.

Procurei demonstrar de forma bastante resumida como abstrair a query da URI de uma forma "universal", onde também podemos aproveitar as mesmas rotinas em ambientes diferentes.

Para um exemplo mais completo, a resposta tornaria-se 2 ou 3 vezes mais extensa. Contudo, com os exemplos acima podemos ver como uma tarefa tão simples na verdade é bastante complexa.

O ideal é montar isso tudo em OOP para que reaproveite as rotinas e otimize as execuções.

Para ter uma noção de como complicar ainda mais, imagine modelos de negócios onde necessita anexar parâmetros específicos no inicío ou no final da query. Um exemplo no mundo real é adicionar um parâmetro que identifique o idioma da UI.

Exemplo `http://localhost/en/conta/fazerlogin`

E ao mesmo tempo também permitir ignorar o parâmetro do idioma

Exemplo `http://localhost/conta/fazerlogin`

Quando não encontrar o parâmetro, o router assinaria um valor padrão e ao mesmo tempo, não pode conflitar com a ordem dos outros parâmetros.

Comment: apresenta o erro: `Internal Server Error`

Comment: é esperado que mod_rewrite esteja já devidamente ativado

Comment: Realmente não estava ativo, umas configurações de um software acabou alterando,mas mesmo assim não deu.. Porém consegui editando o .htaccess e somente com ele

Comment: não posso fazer nada com informações tão vagas.