# Sistema com URL amigável pegar retorno em query string

Tags: php, url-amigável

Estou com um problema com o url de retorno do PayPal, meu sistema tem o conceito de URL amigável por exemplo:

```
http://outros.local/vendas/carrinhos/finalizada
```

Mas com o retorno do PayPal a URL está ficando assim:

```
http://outros.local/vendas/carrinhos/finalizada?token=myToken&PayerID=myID
```

Logo não estou conseguindo captar os atributos `token` e `PayerID`, meu .htacess está assim:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ index.php?url=$1
</IfModule>
```

Tenho também um arquivo chamado *dispenser.php*, a função dele é pegar o parâmetro url e transformar em `controller`, `method` e `params`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Leonardo Vilarinho
 * Date: 09/07/2016
 * Time: 22:05
 */

/**
 * Resgata parametros da URL, separa controller de method, verificando também se o link
 * representa um alias, se representar pega o controlador e metodo do alias, se não pega
 * o padrao do link (site.com/controlador/metodo/parametros). Por fim resgata os demais parametros
 * colocando-o em array para serem usados no controlador.
 *
 * Exemplo:
 * URL -> site.com/pessoas/editar/51
 * Resultado do script será:
 *      $_GET['controller'] = 'pessoas'
 *      $_GET['method'] = 'editar'
 *      $_GET['params'] = array(0 => 51)
 *
 */
var_dump($_GET);
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : '';
unset($_GET['url']);

if(!empty($url))
{
    $params = explode('/', $url);
    $_GET['controller'] = isset($params[0]) ? $params[0] : '';
    $alias = Alias::check($_GET['controller']);
    if($alias != false)
    {
        $_GET['controller'] = explode('/', $alias)[0];
        $_GET['method'] =  explode('/', $alias)[1];
    }
    else
    {
        $_GET['method'] = isset($params[1]) ? $params[1] : '';
        unset($params[1]);
    }

    unset($params[0]);
    $get = array();
    foreach ($params as $value)
        array_push($get, $value);
    $_GET['params'] = $get;
}
```

O erro já aparece no `var_dump`, que é exibido:

```
/home/leonardo/www/outros/vendas/kernel/dispenser.php:23:
array (size=1)
  'url' => string 'carrinhos/finalizada' (length=20)
```

Notei que o problema é o ponto de interrogação na url de retorno (?), pois ficaria assim:

```
http://outros.local/vendas?url=carrinhos/finalizada?token=myToken&PayerID=myID
```

Logo pegaria apenas o primeiro parametro.

Como faço para pegar o restante da URL?

Funcionou assim (pois nesse caso o *Paypal* retorna com o & e não ?):

```
http://outros.local/vendas?controller=carrinhos&method=finalizada&token=myToken&PayerID=myID
```

Mas meu sistema ficaria exposto e com essa url diferente das demais.. Outro que deu certo foi:

```
http://outros.local/vendas/carrinhos/finalizada&token=myToken&PayerID=myID
```

Mas quando coloco o link de retorno do PayPal como  `http://outros.local/vendas/carrinhos/finalizada` não funciona pois o sistema da PayPal retorna a query string iniciando com '?'.

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Olá, Tente adicionar isto ao final de sua regra: RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ index.php?url=$1 **[QSA,NC,L]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um jeito simples de resolver é apenas fazer uma pequena mudança na URL de retorno

A sua URL está assim:

```
http://outros.local/vendas/carrinhos/finalizada
```

Bastaria fazer isso:

```
http://outros.local/vendas/carrinhos/finalizada/?paypal
```

Quando retornar do Paypal receberá algo como

```
http://outros.local/vendas/carrinhos/finalizada/?paypal&token=myToken&PayerID=myID
```

Claro que isso depende de como o seu sistema faz o tratamento da URL.

Mas basicamente pode apenas ler o global `$_GET`.

Processe normalmente a sua URL nesse formato de URL amigável e no model dessa página faria algo assim:

```
if (isset($_GET['token'])) {
    // tchanranran
}
```

## URL amigável provê segurança?

Notei a sua preocupação com esse trecho

> Mas meu sistema ficaria exposto e com essa url diferente das demais..
>   Outro que deu certo foi:

O fato do usuário enxergar ou não os nomes dos parâmetros numa URL não muda em nada a segurança. Portanto, se consegue resolver com mais facilidade **sem** URL amigável, faça dessa forma mais simples ao invés de complicar.

## Opcional

Pode também solicitar para que o retorno seja feito pelo método POST

O nome do parâmetro é "rm". Defina com valor 2 para receber esses dados pelo método POST.

Return method. The FORM METHOD used to send data to the URL specified by the return variable.
Allowable values are:

> 0 — all shopping cart payments use the GET method
>   
> 1 — the buyer's
>   browser is redirected to the return URL by using the GET method, but
>   no payment variables are included
>   
> 2 — the buyer's browser is
>   redirected to the return URL by using the POST method, and all payment
>   variables are included

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Eu lembrava vagamente de algo que postei sobre friendly URL e extração de parâmetros então encontrei isso, que por coincidência foi numa pergunta sua: [Url amigável para MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117749/url-amig%C3%A1vel-para-mvc)