# PHP Built-in e htaccess - Sistema de Rotas / URL Amigável

Tags: php, htaccess, rotas

Possuo um arquivo .htaccess para o desvio de rotas no servidor (produção) e um arquivo router.php para o desvio de rotas usando o Built-in server do PHP 7.

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 router.php
```

Porém, gostaria de usar o **router.php** também em produção, com o mesmo efeito.

Meu servidor tem gerenciamento com WHM e os domínios com CPanel (também com PHP 7, com as mesmas configurações do local).

Note que não se trata apenas de colocar o conteudo no **index.php**, nem de se tranferir a responsabilidade via .htaccess, posto que o arquivo de rotas possui comandos específicos, como o famoso...

```
return false;
```

...para se indicar que o **router.php** deve ser ignorado e ir direto para a pasta da URI.

E isso não funciona em um acesso comum.

Exemplo prático (meramente didático):

Pastas/Arquivos do projeto

```
1 - /api/execute.php
2 - /admin/
3 - /index.php
```

Rotas (URI de Origem):

```
1 - /api/{servico}/{detalhe}
2 - /admin/
3 - /{caminho}/{qualquer}
```

Como fica o .htaccess (produção):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/?.*$ api/execute.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/?(.*)$ admin/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?.*$ index.php
```

Como fica o router.php (local/Built-in):

```
<?php
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server' && is_file(__DIR__ . parse_url($_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], PHP_URL_PATH))) {
    return false;
}

// Inicializa serviço de controle de URI
$uri = new \Config\Uri();

// API
if (preg_match('/^api\/?.*$/', $uri->getUri())) {
    require_once 'api/execute.php';
    exit;
}

// ADMIN
if (preg_match('/^admin\/.*$/', $uri->getUri())) {
    return false;
}

// Site
require_once "index.php";
```

Isso é apenas um exemplo, porém notem o uso de `return false;`. Todas as demais linhas do **router.php** funcionam tanto localmente como em produção.

Mas o  `return false;` que tem como objetivo fazer ignorar o router e seguir o caminho da uri naturalmente, não funciona online, obviamente.

Como proceder?

**Obs**: Trata-se de um sistema antigo que ainda precisa de suporte. Não vale a pena trocar todo o sistema de rotas dele, posto que um novo sistema está sendo criado. Por isso, apenas queria usar o mesmo **router.php** tb em produção para não ter que usar o .htaccess personalizado para cada dominio que usa o sistema.

Comment: Qual é o problema exatamente? Tem bastante informação esparsa na pergunta, mas talvez seja melhor focar na dificuldade enfrentada, descrever o que foi tentado e qual o problema com as tentativas. Em teoria, se você fizer o router.php atender a todas as requisições, deveria funcionar nas duas situações, não?

Comment: @Bacco pronto, coloquei um exemplo pra explicar melhor

Comment: Podereria se explicar melhor?

Comment: Qual parte, @Tmc? Veja os exemplos, por gentileza. Preciso desenvolver um router.php que funcione tanto para o built-in do php como no servidor online, para o exemplo passado. Note que a única parte que não funciona online são as que envolvem usar o "return false"

Comment: Há alguns meses atrás publiquei uma resposta que resolve isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117757/4793  Nesse link parece que o AP não entendeu nada. Eu sei que pode parecer complexo, mas se quiser posso explicar o uso que na verdade é bastante simples e tem suporte inclusive para execuções por command line interface (CLI).

Comment: @DanielOmine Obrigado pelo link. De fato, ajuda bastante, mas parece não resolver. Os links diretos para arquivo funcionou, mas os links diretos para pastas, não. Pode ser que eu não tenha configurado corretamente. Usando o exemplo que eu passei, poderia por gentileza mostrar como configuro o htaccess (e o router, se necessário) para que funcione corretamente? (Em especial quando se é pra acessar uma outra pasta, que conterá suas proprias regras, como o "/admin/" do exemplo...). Já crie uma resposta aqui, por favor, posto que,se resolver, a recompensa é sua ;) Além de ajudar a outros tb

Answer (score 2):

Vamos ver se consigo ajudar, e se percebi bem a pergunta.

Deixo aqui um excerto do código que utilizo numa framework que desenvolvi ao longos dos anos, e que uso em vários projectos PHP.

Em primeiro lugar, o que queremos é um single point no PHP que seja responsável por toda a lógica de routing, e para isso temos de ter algo deste género no ficheiro .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^/?.*$ /pageHandler.php?CUSTOM_HTACCESS_VAR=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Isto vai redireccionar todos os pedidos para o pageHandler, e todos os dados do URL estarão acessíveis em `$_GET['CUSTOM_HTACCESS_VAR']` (alternativamente Isto também pode ser feito e acedido através de variáves internas de PHP, como `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`)

No pageHandler, criamos uma instância da minha classe de parsing, e chamamos o método processPage.

O conteúdo da class Parser fica aqui (apenas a parte relevante):

```
<?php
class Parser {
    var $URL;
    var $file; // the current PHP file being used
    var $vars;
    var $path;
    var $timer;
    var $fullPathExists = true;

    function __construct() {
        $this->requestID = uniqid(md5(rand()), true);

        $varName = "CUSTOM_HTACCESS_VAR";
        $this->URL = array();
        if (isset($_GET[$varName])) {
            if (substr($_GET[$varName], 0, 1) == "/") $_GET[$varName] = substr($_GET[$varName], 1);
            $url = explode("/", $_GET[$varName]);
            $this->URL = $url;
        }

        unset($_GET[$varName]);
        $this->vars = array();
        $this->path = array();

        $dir = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/Pages/";
        $tamanhoURL = count($this->URL);
        for($i = 0; $i < $tamanhoURL; $i++) {
            $tempDir = "{$dir}{$this->URL[$i]}/";
            if (!is_dir($tempDir)) {
                break;
            }
            $dir = $tempDir;
            $this->path[] = $this->URL[$i];
        }

        # verifica se existe dentro da ultima pasta um ficheiro com o nome que nao é o index
        if (($i < $tamanhoURL) && file_exists("{$dir}{$this->URL[$i]}.php")) {
            $file = "{$dir}{$this->URL[$i]}.php";
            $script = $this->URL[$i];
            $this->path[] = $this->URL[$i];
            $i++;
        }
        else {
            $file = "{$dir}index.php";
            $script = "index";
        }

        $this->file = $file;

        for (;$i < $tamanhoURL - 1; $i++) {
            $this->vars[$this->URL[$i]] = $this->URL[++$i];
            $this->fullPathExists = false;
        }
        if ($i < $tamanhoURL) {
            $this->vars['SINGLE'] = $this->URL[$i];
            $this->fullPathExists = false;
        }

    }


    function processPage() {
        if (file_exists($this->file)) {
            require($this->file);
        }
        else {
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            header("Status: 404 Not Found");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Espero que ajude. Poderás ter de adaptar o código para funcionar nesses sites que já têm uma estrutura própria, que pode diferir da que utilizo.

De notar ainda que esta classe guardar numa variável de nome vars todas as partes do URL que não correspondem a um ficheiro, e que podem ser usadas numa perspectiva de uma framework MVC.

Por exemplo o URL /teste/xpto/fazer/action pode servir para carregar o ficheiro /teste/xpto.php, e na variavel vars fica um elemento, de nome 'fazer' com o valor 'action'.

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, mas não é isso. Note que sua classe devolve um 404 para quando o arquivo não existe. Isso significa q não posso chamar na URL uma pasta (como "/admin/", do exemplo). E o problema está justamente aí. Quando - no exemplo - a url apontar para a pasta admin, ele deve ignorar o roteamento e ir pra lá.

Comment: @Szag-Ot Para isso basta uma pequena alteração na classe ou no processPage. Como poderá verificar, na variável $this->path existe um array com o caminho que foi possível reconstruir e que pode ser utilizado dentro do else do método processPage, ou então aceder à variável local $dir que é utilizada no construtor.